# Is the use of WebClient the proper way to transfer a file if statuscode are needed?

Tags: c#, file-upload, ftp

Like the title says, I'm wondering if the use of WebClient is the proper tool to use for transfering a file to a ftp on a daily basis? After a bit of reading around, it seems to me that it does not return the ftps response codes.

Can anyone recommend good practice on this, alternatively recommend what part of the framework to use?

I guess that the third alternative would be to rewrite the existing Ftp-functionality.

The following exists today, and are it's being called from another class:

```
using System.Net;

public class WebClientAdapter : IWebClientAdapter
{
    private WebClient _webClient = new WebClient();

    public ICredentials Credentials
    {
        get { return _webClient.Credentials; }
        set { _webClient.Credentials = value; }
    }

    public byte[] UploadFile(string address, string fileName)
    {
        return _webClient.UploadFile(address, fileName);
    }


using System.Net;

    public class FtpHandler
    {

        public string Path { get; private set; }
        private const string Uri = "PathToFtp";
        private const string FileName = "SomeFile";

        private IWebClientAdapter _webClientAdapter;

        public IWebClientAdapter WebClientAdapter
        {
            get
            {
                if (_webClientAdapter == null)
                    _webClientAdapter = new WebClientAdapter();
                return _webClientAdapter;
            }
            set { _webClientAdapter = value; }
        }

        public FtpHandler()
        {
            Path = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.GetTempPath(), FileName);
        }

        public void Upload()
        {
            WebClientAdapter.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "pass");
            WebClientAdapter.UploadFile(Uri, Path);
        }
    }
```

I removed some namespaces, credentials and names due to company policy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider using the [FtpWebRequest-Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest%28v=vs.80%29) - it has everything you need.